# Meteor MongoDB, trying to get SUM of a field to client

Tags: mongodb, meteor, sum, field

I am running Meteor in Localhost

I have a collection named Transactions, which has fields like user, amount, date and description

I would like to get the sum of "amount" field for a particular user. Which are the steps I should take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More information would be helpful, but from my understanding the solution is,

**If you want to do this in client side**

1) first subscribe to all the user (in client)

```
  Meteor.subscribe("userTransactions");
```

publish function look like

```
 in server side code


Meteor.publish("userTransactions,function(){
  return Transactions.find({user:this.userId}); 
});
```

//this.userId return the id of the user who requested this publish function `null` if no one loggedin

2) In the client helpers

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  'sum':function(){
     var sum=0;
     var cursor=Transactions.find({user:Meteor.userId()});
     cursor.forEach(function(transaction){
       sum = sum + transaction.amount
     });
     return sum;
   }
})
```

**If you want to do this in server**

1) create a method in server side with the same code return the sum

2) call the method from client

Comment: @MaheshBabu, can you create a minimum replication of code in meteorpad.com which shows the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
// on server

Meteor.methods({
  userSum: function() {
    var userTransactions = Transactions.find({ userId: this.userId }).fetch();

    return _.reduce(userTransactions, function(sum, next) {
      return sum + next.amount;
    }, 0);
  }
});

// on client, assuming a user is logged in

Meteor.call('userSum', function(mySum) {
  console.log(mySum);
});
```

Comment: @MaheshBabu Could you explain? What isn't working? We need a few more details to help you solve the problem. I changed `Meteor.userId()` to `this.userId`, does that help?